selenium chromedriver error 0xc0000005 on windows 7
I have developed a windows form app with selenium on vs2019 and dotnet 4.6.1 the app works perfectly on windows 10 64-bit where I originally create the app and debug it. but I need it for win7 and it doesn't work on windows 7 64-bit and it throws 0xc0000005 with code 1073741819. When I open the file bin/debug/selenium-manager/windows/selenium-manager.exe as administrator the same thing happens.
the error happens at this line:
driver = new ChromeDriver(options: ChromeOptions);

Is there any incompatibility issue between selenium manager OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome and windows 7?

The problem is solved! I think there is some difference between environment variables Windows 7 and Windows 10. I got the idea from this post and the problem is solved!
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"c:\chromedriver.exe");

I copied the chromedriver.exe to some specific place and called it directly. I replaced the code I mentioned in the question with above code and chrome driver is working fine.
